# Wire size of unmarked wires

Tags: circuit-breaker

Can anyone guess the size of these wires? They are not marked.[image: K]

Comment: 10 gauge solid core copper wires.

Comment: I rubbed the paint off of my wires. The littlest is 14-2

Comment: The big wire is 12-3 type 8.  I have a cool 25 amp double pole, double throw ?breaker. Can I put my two circuits (red and black) on this breaker

Comment: 12 AWG is good for 20 amperes, while 14 AWG is good for 15 amperes. None of these wires should be protected by a 25 ampere breaker.

Comment: Okay thanks . what is commonly used with that kind of breaker? It looks unusual. Thanks

Comment: Typically an A/C unit or some kind of motor. In both of those cases #12 on a 25A would likely be fine, but NOT for any kind of general use circuit.

Answer (score 3):

There should be markings on the cable jacket. If you can't read it due to age, measure the thickness of the wires with a caliper, or a pair of wire strippers. Modern NM cables are color coded, but older cable was not. So jacket color means nothing with older cable.

Checking the size of the breaker could give you a clue, but only if the cable was installed properly. If wired properly, 12 AWG should be used on a 20 amp circuit, while 14 AWG is good for 15 amp circuits.

14 AWG wires are fairly easy to bend, while 12 AWG are a bit stiffer. Though this is only helpful, if you're familiar with working with wires.

If you had a piece of wire of a known size, you could use that to compare. Though you'll want to compare the metal part of the wire, as the insulation may be slightly different even on the same size wires.